# Moengage Push Notification Click Not Redirecting While App On Foreground/Running in Background

Tags: ios, flutter, moengage

Hello I am currently running a Flutter app that is using Moengage to send push notifications. Currently, the notification is receiving just fine. But, there is a problem that only occurs in iOS: the notification is not redirecting to specified link when the notification is clicked when the application is currently opened/running in background. Is there any specific configuration that I might have missed? Sorry I am unable to give a piece of code but based on the documentation I don't think there is much things to be done in the setup after push notifications are received perfectly right?

Answer (score 0):

When a user taps on a Push Notification Banner you will get a call in This method.

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)
```

Check Apple's documentation for this here [Apple's documentation for this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428430-application)

Please do remember to set The `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to receive a callback.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    // Set UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    
    return true
}
```

Comment: Isn't the function called when a notification is received? Not when a notification is clicked? Is there a wrong typing in your answer or is that the actual answer?

Answer (score 0):

To handle push callback, you can follow the documentation mentioned [here](https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/11652033989396-Push-Callback). If you are facing any issue in getting callback, the issue could be other libraries like Firebase are interfering with method swizzling. In such case, you can implement callback manually following the documentation mentioned [here](https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403930540820-Push-Notification-Implementation#h_01H92ZQDWH8BSRH5WC0T4KTY2A).

If you are still facing issue, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on what you have tried so far so that we can provide more accurate suggestion.